# Check multiple columns for values then perform operations on them

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have an excel sheet with values in ranges E10:1610 and if cell J5 is equal to "Yes" I want to use vba to check the entire range of columns for values higher than 10. Add all these values together and find 5% of the total.
Here comes the tricky part...if a value is greater than 20, then we will calculate that value as 20. So if i come across a value such as 21, or 35, I will equate that value to 20. So for instance if i find, 11,13,17,29,23, I will calculate 5% of 11 + 13 + 17 + 20 + 20.
Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for VBA

```
=IF(J5="Yes",SUMPRODUCT((E10:E1610>=10)*(E10:E1610<20),E10:E1610)*0.05+(COUNTIF(E10:E1610,">=20")),"")
```

What it does is check for >=10 and <20, then sum x .05. It also counts entries that are 20 or more and adds that to the total. Being that 5% of 20 is 1, the counting does the job.

Comment: so i tried your formula and it doesn't quite work. If i enter 100 in E10, the result will be 1 when it should actually be 20 times .05

Comment: the formula works for values below 20 but is supposed to equate all values over 20 to 20

Comment: I'm new to this site. I believe you are supposed to mark it as solved.

Comment: I wanna ask you something else, how can I perform operations on individual cells. For example i have a sheet and i want to compare the totals to some totals on a document. However the document sums up the figures after they have been doubled then rounded individually. However in excel i will get a mismatch if i sum all the figures then double them. I want to know if there is a way i can perform operations on individual cells. Example the above operation on a cell per cell basis then round them individually before totaling them.

Comment: One more question for the above formula. How can I factor in another condition like checking if J5="Yes" and A10:A610="No"

Comment: What I realized is that the formula doesnt hold true for other values. lets say i change the range to >11538 and <= 34760 will go at 5% anything over 34760 will be equated to 34760. so if i get a 40000 value that will be 5% of 34760

Comment: Not in front of a computer to get the exact formula, but multiply the counif x .05 x whatever that max number is.

Comment: yes got it to work by multiplying the count by the limit number then that by the percentage. I also rounded it and am getting the correct values as per the document.
=ROUND(IF(J5="Yes",SUMPRODUCT((E10:I610>11538)*(E10:I610<=34760),E10:I610)*0.056+(COUNTIF(E10:I610,">34760")*34760)*0.056,""),0)
My final question would be how to factor in another condition to make sure A10:A610 = "No" also before the calculations are carried out

Comment: Got the extra condition to work
=ROUND(IF(J5="Yes",SUMPRODUCT((E10:I610>11538)*(E10:I610<=34760)*(A10:A610="No"),E10:I610)*0.056+(COUNTIF(E10:I610,">34760")*34760)*0.056,""),0)
However i just realized that the round is done on the entire sum. Can I somehow calculate per cell and roud per cell too?